# MIEngine Debugging works for Launch but not Attach on Linux

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a project that I have been debugging on Linux using the MIEngine and clrdbg. When I launch the application from Visual Studio, the debugger attaches fine and my breakpoints are hit. If I run the application as a daemon started by the system, Visual Studio appears to let me attach the debugger to the process, but there is no output in the output window (besides the initial header explaining what I am allowed to do with the debugging tools), and none of my breakpoints are hit.

I am using VS2015 and using Debug.MIDebugLaunch in the Command Window either way. Here are what my Options Files look like...

For Launching the application from Visual Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PipeLaunchOptions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/MDDDebuggerOptions/2014"
  PipePath="path-to\plink.exe" PipeArguments="-i path-to\ssh-debug.ppk user@machinename -batch -t ~/clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi"
  TargetArchitecture="x64" MIMode="clrdbg" ExePath="dotnet" WorkingDirectory="~/workingDirectory" ExeArguments="ApplicationName.dll">
</PipeLaunchOptions>
```

For Attaching to the running application from Visual Studio (I change the ProcessId if I restart the service and it comes up under a different ID):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PipeLaunchOptions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/MDDDebuggerOptions/2014"
  PipePath="path-to\plink.exe" PipeArguments="-i path-to\ssh-debug.ppk user@machinename -batch -t ~/clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi"
  TargetArchitecture="x64" MIMode="clrdbg" ProcessId="19036">
  <LaunchCompleteCommand>None</LaunchCompleteCommand>
</PipeLaunchOptions>
```

Any ideas about what might be happening, or what I'm missing?
Is this a bug, or do I perhaps need to update something?

**EDIT:**
I changed my "attach" Options File to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PipeLaunchOptions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/MDDDebuggerOptions/2014"
  PipePath="path-to\plink.exe" PipeArguments="-i path-to\ssh-debug.ppk user@machinename -batch -t ~/clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi --attach 19036"
  TargetArchitecture="x64" MIMode="clrdbg">
  <LaunchCompleteCommand>None</LaunchCompleteCommand>
</PipeLaunchOptions>
```

And it works, but now I can't figure out how to detach the debugger without killing the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.VisualCforLinuxDevelopment) has fixed the issue and made it work correctly with the ProcessId attribute to PipeLaunchOptions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Done. I wasn't able to mark it as the solution yet last time I was at my desk. :)